# How to modify Blob storage path for Azure Web App Diagnostics logs

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I have a .Net Core 2.0 Web service which is deployed on Microsoft Azure. In my application I am using Azure Web App Diagnostics to store logs in the Blob storage.

The logs files are split according to hours. Currently the blob file path would be something like {year}/{month}/{date}/{hour}/{filename}. Having a new folder for every hour.

I want to change this storage path and store daily logs in one file. I am using **LoggerFactory** for logging. I have added the **AzureWebAppDiagnostics** in the **Configure** method in **Startup.cs**

```
loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(
            new AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings
            {
                OutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [{Level}] {RequestId}-{SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
            );
```

I understand that there are other ways of logging such as using NLog or SeriLog but is there any out of the box way of doing what I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently the blob file path would be something like {year}/{month}/{date}/{hour}/{filename}. Having a new folder for every hour. I want to change this storage path and store daily logs in one file.

I checked the `class AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings` and find that it just enables us to specify the last section of log blob name, it does not enable us to specify the full name of blob.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the last section of log blob name. Defaults to "applicationLog.txt".
public string BlobName { get; set; }
```

You can [open an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues) and track the status. Besides, as you mentioned, you can integrate NLog etc to write log to Azure Storage.